# Nextjs redux, thunk and getInitialProps - how to implement

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to use `nextjs` in my new project with `redux` and `thunk` also. I wondering how to implement all packages correctly.

In my previous projects pages has `HOC` components like:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Page from './about';
import {fetchUsers} from '../../actions/user';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {users} = state;
    return users;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page);
```

And method to fetch users I implemented in `componentDidMount`

How to implement the same logic for `nexjs`?

What have I do?

1. Implemented store (base on next-redux-wrapper in _app.js)
2. Created `HOC` component (like below) with `mapStateToProps` and
   `mapDispatchToProps`

Currently I thinking about use somehow `this.props.fetchUsers` method into `getInitialProps` - documentation say that this method should be used to fetch data before render site.

Please help me with correctly `redux` implementation for `nextjs`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow this [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper)
The correct way is to pass the store to the `getInitialProps` context and to the `App` component so you can pass it to the `Provider`.

The `getInitialProps` can't access to instance of the component, this is not accessible, so you can't call `this.props.fetchUsers`, but, because you are passing store to its context, you can do `store.dispatch(fetchUsers())` and remove dispatch from `mapDispatchToProps`.

Generally I dispatch actions in `getInitialProps` and then map state to props within `connect`.

Comment: So `mapDispatchToProps` is unnecessary in `nextjs` for that?

Comment: how do that after refresh page? I mean on server side? On Client side it's working (used Link) but on server not.

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` is unnecessary in pages if you dispatch actions only in `getInitialProps`. Furthermore, it should work even if you reload the page. If you are using redux devtools, you will not see dispatched action because on reload it is made server side.

Comment: But on server side it doesn't work. As I investigated store.dispatch not work on server side. I tried console log in reducer but on server console it doesn't present.

Comment: please does this mean that there is not need to implement 'componentDidMount' for fetching the data on the client side for client side routing ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah it depends on your needs. If you have to dispatch actions in routes you can avoid `componentDidMount`

Comment: @marczak you need to use with `await`, like this: `await store.dispatch(...)`

Comment: Take a look at `connect-initial-props`, this is a small decorator I've created to get state and dispatch easily from `getInitialProps` https://github.com/webiya/connect-initial-props